# Is this MacBook Pro charger safe to use?

Tags: charging, charger

I happen to accidentally jam my charger in between a few moving objects and this was, unfortunately, the resut. Is this still safe to use? Are there any risks to continuing using assuming it will still charge my MacBook Pro?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know from a simple visual examination.
You have three options...

1. *[the cavalier]* Try it & see what happens
2. *[the circumspect]* Take it to be tested
3. *[the disposable income]* Buy a new one & throw that one away.